# Wrong MonthDayPattern in Silverlight on PC with German Windows

Tags: silverlight, cultureinfo, datetimeformatinfo

I am facing a really strange issue into a PC with German Windows Server 2003 installed. It is important to mark that this doesn't happen on a PC with English Windows installed even if I set Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture and Language to German. It also doesn't happen if I set the display language of the Windows to German. It happens only in Silverlight (doesn't happen in WPF or a console application).

The issue is simple - the value of the MonthDayPattern of the current Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat is "MMMM.dd". Into every other PC I test this with Culture, UICulture and Language set to German the value is "dd.MMMM".

Comment: A similar issue now appears on a pc with UK Windows 2000 installed.